# What does "use keystrokes to scroll on alternate screen" mean?

Tags: gnome-terminal

"use keystrokes to scroll on alternate screen" is an option in gnome-terminal profile preferences. 
It seems that the person who wrote the help doesn't know either because he skipped that option in the gnome-terminal manual. What is going on? That happens at least in Ubuntu-Natty, but I doubt they have fixed that.

Answer:
Hahaha.. It should be "enable the use of mouse scroll on alternate screen (an alternate screen is a screen superimposed when you read man pages for example)" and not “use keystrokes to scroll on alternate screen” . Hahaha. the meaning is the opposite. What is going on with quality control in UBuntu? They are ruining the prestige of Linux.

Who will correct that??

Comment: Make a bug report

Answer (score 3):

Robert solved the problem ([as seen in his question](https://askubuntu.com/q/142622/44179)):

> Hahaha.. It should be "enable the use of mouse scroll on alternate screen (an alternate screen is a screen superimposed when you read man pages for example)" and not “use keystrokes to scroll on alternate screen” . Hahaha. the meaning is the opposite. What is going on with quality control in UBuntu? They are ruining the prestige of Linux.